# Matlab generate smooth curve between scatter points

Tags: matlab, interpolation, curve-fitting, normals

I need to generate a curve between scatter points then identify the unit normal of the curve at each point. Here is an example of a point cloud

```
figure
x = [1 2 0 0 1 1 2 3 4 2];
y = [4 6 9 1 1 2 4 9 2 3];
scatter(x,y)
hold on
line(x,y)
xlim([0 4])
ylim([0 10])
```

[image]

NOTE: the 2 points along the y-axis are connected

Instead of a line between the points, I'd like to create a smooth curve. I'm not sure how to do this when points in x and y repeat. An attempt using `spline` fails. After I know the curve, I need to find the unit normals at each point. How do I go about this?

EDIT:
Basically I want to do what is show here for `polyfit` in the [matlab docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html). Assuming that x was unique in my case, this wouldn't be an issue. I could identify the polynomial and then, I believe, determine the unit normals from the polynomial function evaluated at that point. But in my case, the x and y data repeat so a straight forward application doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but basically start at one of the end points and connect the dots with a smooth curve instead of a straight line. Then I need to find the unit normals to that curve at the point locations. I suspect that what I need to know is how to define such a function then do some derivatives to get to the unit normals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get a smooth path is to treat this as a parametric function and interpolate x and y separately.

```
x = [1 2 0 0 1 1 2 3 4 2];
y = [4 6 9 1 1 2 4 9 2 3];
t = 1:numel(x);

tq = 1:0.1:t(end);
xq = interp1(t,x,tq,'v5cubic');
yq = interp1(t,y,tq,'v5cubic');

plot(x,y,' ob',xq,yq,'-r');
```

To estimate the normals you can take the average normal of the two line segments around the sample points. This code is a bit ugly but it gets the job done.

```
n = zeros(2,numel(x));
for tidx = 1:numel(t)
    tt = t(tidx);
    idx1 = find(tq <= tt,1,'last');
    idx0 = idx1 - 1;
    idx2 = idx1 + 1;
    if idx0 > 0
        n1 = [yq(idx1) - yq(idx0); xq(idx0) - xq(idx1)];
        n(:,tidx) = n(:,tidx) + n1/norm(n1);
    end
    if idx2 <= numel(tq)
        n2 = [yq(idx2) - yq(idx1); xq(idx1) - xq(idx2)];
        n(:,tidx) = n(:,tidx) + n2/norm(n2);
    end
    n(:,tidx) = n(:,tidx) / norm(n(:,tidx));
end

plot(x,y,' ob',xq,yq,'-r',[x.' x.'+n(1,:).'].', [y.' y.'+n(2,:).'].',' -k');
axis equal;
```

[image]

If you use `pchip` instead of `v5cubic` for the interpolation method then you get more symmetry around the sample points. However, it appears that any sharp turns (90 degrees or greater) are not smoothed.

[image]

Comment: Ha...funny! I was just finished reviewing this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292114/matlab-interpolating-a-2d-curve-with-multiple-ys-per-x?rq=1 to see if it might offer a solution and I see you more or less followed the same concept. I'll try to implement your solution and see if it works.